# Can't connect to Beaglebone Green via Chrome

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I just got a Beaglebone Green for Christmas (!), but am having a hard time connected to it via Chrome based on the startup directions at http://beagleboard.org/getting-started.

My main computer is running Ubuntu 14.04.  When I run ifconfig, I can see the 'bone on 192.168.7.2 and can ssh in as root.  But according to the webpage directions, I should be able to connect to it via http to that address using Chrome.  However, when I do, all I get is ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I am obviously happy to run from the command prompt, but I would prefer to get that warm fuzzy that comes with being able to follow all of the directions on the startup.  So any tips for what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if you need to add a portnumber?

Like `192.168.7.2:1234`

Chrome will take `port 80` by default.

**Update**:

Seems to listen on `port 8080`.

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs indicating it should **not** be 80, much less another port to try.

Comment: Ok, and what if you try port 3000?

Comment: I got the Cloud9 IDE.  Interesting.  Any ideas on which port gets me to their intro presentation as decribed in ["Browse to your board"](http://beagleboard.org/getting-started#step3)?

Comment: Hard to tell (long shot, try :8080). Also make sure you have te latest firmware. Also make sure there's no conflicting device with 192.168.7.2.

Comment: Or try connecting via a router.

Comment: A good guess.  According to /etc/apache2/ports.conf, it is listening on 8080.  But using that still gave me "Index of /".  It appears that apache doesn't know where to find its webpages at.  There is nothing in /var/www and just linking to the correct index.html (at /var/lib/cloud9/) does not preserve the directory structure.  Ah well.  Something for me that I can fix now.  Thank you!

Comment: Ok, good luck! (and what about :8080/index.html or /index.htm ?)

Comment: Tried that.  There are too many directory structures that get confused.  All I did was edit the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default file to set DocumentRoot  to "/var/lib/cloud9" and the corresponding "<Directory "..."> " and that seems to have solved it.  Whew!